# How to send remote users a link or python command that will play a sound on my helpdesk computer

Tags: python

I'd like to supply a way (in Python) to let my colleagues alert me to specific situations by simply executing a tiny Python file on their local desktop that would play a ringtone (mp3 or wav) on my Windows 10 desktop PC.  My current software allows messaging, but the messages make no sound when they arrive (and cannot be configured to do so).  I'm often sitting elsewhere in the office and don't see their messages.

Any ideas?  I considered just writing an ASP (or similar) web app, but that's not what I want.  I specifically want Python, as everyone in our group has it.

Thanks!
Mike

I've already tried remote shell commands, PowerShell code, and other scripting languages.
I just need a way for a Python file that plays a sound to be safely launched on my PC by select remote staff.

Comment: would a requirement of a websever be ok?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A properly secured Web app is likely the best bet in your situation—it will give you far greater ability to lock down access security-wise, reducing the risk of your handy tool leading to a security breach for your company.

Answer (score -1):

The following solution works for `.wav` files and if you expose your computer's `8080` port over the network.  Tested with `python3.9` on Windows 11.

```
pip install playsound flask
```

```
# server.py

from flask import Flask, request
from playsound import playsound
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    # Getting the user's IP
    user_ip = request.remote_addr

    # Getting the current date and time
    current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    # Playing the .mp3 file
    playsound('tada.wav')

    print(f"Date and Time: {current_datetime}, IP: {user_ip}")

    return "Sound played."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Start the server with:

```
python server.py
```

While this flask server is running on the host...

Opening a web browser to http://127.0.0.1:8080 will play the sound on your computer.

Port forwarding and exposing a port to other people in your group is another issue.

For someone else to trigger this (assuming they can see your computer over the router) it might be something like:

```
http://192.168.1.12:8080
#              ^^^^  depends on the ip address assigned by the router
```

Open it in a web browser and refresh every time they want to make your computer play `tada.wav`.

From a commandline in windows it would be something like:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

```
C:\Users\username> curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Sound played.
```

If you find an `mp3` file you want to use, either convert it to a `wav` file using `Audacity > export as .wav` or switch to a bigger library for playing sounds such as:

```
pip install pydub simpleaudio
```

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

# Load the .mp3 file
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("tada.mp3")

# Play the .mp3 file
play(song)
```

Move the above lines into the other flask webserver script appropriately.